# Como passar parâmetro em NSarray na url NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, api, url, xcode

Estou criando um UITableView para carregar os favoritos que estão salvos no NSUserDefaults, os valores sao os IDs. ex. 34, 45, 55...

estou criando o url e passando parâmetro através de um NSMutableArray. (34, 45, 55). da seguinte forma.

```
    NSString * porGeral = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.../api/listarFavoritos.php?listaCli=%@", @"34, 45, 55"];


    url = [NSURL URLWithString:porGeral];

    NSLog(@"%@", porGeral);

    NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask * task =
    [session downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSData * jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
        news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@", news);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.progressView removeFromSuperview];

        });
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

O Erro apresentado:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Seu eu passar dessa forma a url no browser não apresenta o erro, entao consegui idenficar que este erro está no NSURLSessionDownloadTask.

Alguma sugestao?

valeu a todos.

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorre ao passar um parâmetro nulo ao método JSONObjectWithData.

Provavelmente o download do arquivo está falhando e quando o *completionHandler* é chamado o valor de *location* é *nil*.

Como boa prática, sempre adicione tratamento para exceções. Isso não só previne crashes, mas também ajuda a indentificar a raíz do problema:

```
[session downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading URL: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot create data from URL");
        return;
    }

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
    if (jsonParsingError) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", jsonParsingError);
        return;
    }

   //... 
}];
```

Se a execução atingir o final do bloco, *news* contém um objeto, mas não há garantia que é do tipo array já que *JSONObjectWithData:* pode retornar outros tipos, como *NSDictionary*.

Outra dica, caso não seja realmente necessário fazer o download, utilize o método dataTaskWithRequest ao invés de downloadTaskWithURL, uma vez que esse já retorna um objeto do tipo NSData.

Comment: Opa Rafael obrigado pelas dicas, agora que vi que estou fazendo com downloadTaskWithURL estava usando em outra aplicação que realmente faz download. valeu pela dica.